# How to select the elements in the array?

Tags: javascript, winforms, c#-4.0, awesomium

Using Awesomium .net for windows forms.

My code-behinde to call a java script functions passing arguments(JSValue).

```
JSValue[] args = new JSValue[args2.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < args2.Length; i++)
{
args[i] = args2[i].ToString();
}

JSObject js_obj = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("window");
//args has all my 35 elements.
js_obj.Invoke("addTheseElements", args);
```

REFERENCE 
http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_Invoke.htm
http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/784/calling-a-javascript-method-with-parameters.html

My HTML page

```
<script>

function addTheseElements(args) {

alert(args);
//returns element1

alert(args[0]);
//returns e

alert (args.length) 
//returns 8 (element1)

}

</script>
```

Problem is that I'm not able to select the 2nd element in the array. How do i access it? What am i doing wrong?

[image: Structure of JSValue. Available properties and methods]

Comment: have you tried `alert(args2.Length)` before  `JSValue[] args = new JSValue[args2.Length];` just to see if you have the correct number of elements that you want?

Comment: Yes i did. I'm passing all the 35 elements to the function call.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it but turns out that the second parameter I need to pass is JSValue object and not an JSValue[].

So my working answer was

```
        JSValue[] args = new JSValue[args2.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < args2.Length; i++)
        {
            args[i] = args2[i].ToString();

        }

        JSValue args3 = args;

        JSObject js_obj = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("window");

        js_obj.Invoke("addTheseElements", args3);
```

But the syntax given in the documentation was

```
public JSValue Invoke(
    string methodName,
    params JSValue[] args
)
```

REF http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_Invoke.htm

Please feel free to explain if anybody finds out what happened here.

Cheers.

Comment: Could there be an implicit conversion here `args[i] = args2[i].ToString();` that i`t becomes `String` instead of `JSValue` object? Try instead `args[1].push(args2[i].ToString();`.

Comment: Sorry but the push extension is not available for .NET version. For the conversion that you pointed out,i've also tried to create new JSValue like this 
args[i] = new JSValue(args2[i].ToString()); but no luck. Only the one above worked.

Comment: have you tried push_back instead of push like `args[i].push_back(args2[i].ToString());`

Comment: push_back not available.

Comment: I am trying to push my luck more (pun intended), have you tried exact assignment like `args[i] = args2[i]`?

Comment: CHECK THE IMAGE, and yes i have tried a lot of different ways before posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this one:

```
args[i] = args2[i].ToString();
```

To:

```
args[i].push_back(args2[i].ToString());
```

before passing.

So that it would become:

```
JSValue[] args = new JSValue[args2.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < args2.Length; i++)
{
 args[i].push_back(args2[i].ToString());
}

JSObject js_obj = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("window");

js_obj.Invoke("addTheseElements", args);
```